# How to upload custom sitemap.xml in shopify?

Tags: xml, shopify, sitemap, web.sitemap

I need to overwrite those generated sitemap. is there any way to do that?

**Main Sitemap Url**
https://www.samplesite.com/sitemap.xml

**Nested Url for pages:**
https://www.samplesite.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml

So, every URL's are automatically generated by shopify. How to edit those sitemap urls and nested urls.

Answer (score 0):

You don't edit sitemap files. On a hosted platform like Shopify you accept that they generate correct sitemap files to suit your needs.